# Delete a node in java preference store that contains a period

Tags: java, install4j

Im trying to clear the users' java.util.prefs.Preferences node of my java application when uninstalling. For this, im using the "Delete a node or key in the Java preference store" action in my uninstaller step to delete the package that i save the preferences in.

This works (on windows) for a package name that contains no period ("test"). The package gets deleted in the registry.

However, if the package contains a period ("test.test"), i can't get it to work.

The error message I get in the installation.log:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.registry.DeletePreferenceItemAction [ID 1006]: Execute action
       Property key: 
       Property onlyIfEmpty: false
       Property preferenceDeleteType: User specific
       Property packageName: test.test
       Property rollbackSupported: true
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.registry.DeletePreferenceItemAction [ID 1006]: Package test.test does not exist
        Execute action not successful after 2 ms
```

This is the configuration of the "Delete a node or key in the Java preference store" action:

```
Package name: test.test
Key: i left this empty (i want to delete the entire package)
Preference root: User specific
```

the other values are the defaults.

I've also tried the following package name values:

```
test\.test
"test.test"
```

But to no avail. We already have alot of users with the registry entries, so preferably we do not rename the package name. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install4j transforms entered package names to path names, so "." is replaced with "/". I have have added escaping to 6.0.5, so entering "test.test" will work starting with that version. To get a pre-release build, please contact support@ej-technologies.com.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ingo! Is the pre-release build otherwise fully stable? Because we would want to immediately deploy software with the feature. If it is not stable, is there an ETA on an official release with that feature? And is there a workaround to make this work with the current version of install4j?

Comment: Yes, you can use the pre-release builds for bugfix releases, that's standard practice for our customers. ETA for 6.0.5 is December at this point. I don't see any workaround for 6.0.4.